# Flask POST method from browser

Tags: javascript

I am using following curl command to perform a POST method of a FLASK REST service.

```
curl -u az:abc_123 -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"filename":"Pattern.json"}' http:/localhost:5300/hcm_code/api/v1.2/get_code
```

How to do the same `POST` method from a browser?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript but it will be no easier than the method you use.

For the proven, simple and effective solution use `jQuery` JavaScript library, add it to your HTML page and use `$.post` function that it provides. You can absolutely use JSON from JavaScript too.

You might have to worry about CORS headers. These are headers that can allow or disallow a request from different server (`http://localhost:80` vs `http://localhost:5300`) and are sent along with a response (from `http://localhost:5300` in your case)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer but my application is in Flask Python. The service is running and I can perform GET & POST functions using curl command. However, I want to to do same from a browser (e.g. Google Chrome).

Comment: Yes, but the browser runs JavaScript. There's no real way to make a post request from a browser except using JavaScript or using `<FORM method="POST">` tag in HTML. The latter is out of the question because it doesn't send JSON formatted data.

Comment: I know you expect it to be something like entering a URL in address bar (which issues a GET) but in a different way, but it's not like that.

Comment: Still it's like 5 lines of JavaScript. Look up examples of using `jQuery.post` function.